# What are some must-read EWDs?

Tags: computer-science, dijkstra

Dijkstra was one of the most prolific computer scientists. He wrote the famous [EWDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edsger_W._Dijkstra#EWDs_and_writing_by_hand). It is not feasible to read them all. But I think there are some we all must read.

Which of them are a **must-read**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Funny. I blogged about this: *[The E. W. Dijkstra Archive (Update)](http://slott-softwarearchitect.blogspot.com/2009/08/e-w-dijkstra-archive-wow.html)*. I think this may be pretty important, because it parallels the *[A Discipline of Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013215871X)* book.

See also EWD316, *[A Short Introduction to the Art of Programming](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/ewd03xx/EWD316.PDF)*.

Answer (score 8):

I recommend starting with his chapter in "Structured Programming".  Not an EWD, technically, but my favorite Dijkstra.  I also strongly recommend Stepanov's "Elements of Programming".  In my mind, Stepanov is our generation's Dijkstra.

Answer (score 4):

I've you've not been introduced to it in a formal setting (i.e. at school or university), you can probably benefit from exposure to Dijkstra's method of program construction, a very rigid but powerful technique for documenting and making accountable one's thought processes when designing programs and algorithms.

*A discipline of programming* would probably be a good start (as would Roland Backhouse's *Program Construction*), but I think in terms of pure impact, it's best to see someone skilled in the technique use it to good effect.  His lecture [The power of counting arguments](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/videos/EWD4.mpg) (hosted at the University of Texas) is a good demonstration for this purpose.

Comment: +1: Also David Gries' *Scientific Programming*.